# TypeScript CLI: How to save octect-stream response from node-fetch call to Get Request?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-fetch

I am making a Get Request using Node-Fetch to a web api.  It returns octet-stream response to be saved as a file in a local.

I tried using downloadjs (download()) and download.js (downloadBlob()), but both of them did not work.

downloadBlob() returned "createObjectURL is not a function" error, and download() returned "window is not defined at object." error.

The call is below

```
let res = await fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
```

I think I am completely lost here.  What should I do to download the file to local drive? How should I construct .then block here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`downloadjs` and `download.js` won't help because these are front end libraries that trigger the download process in a browser. For instance, when you generate an image on the client (in browser) and want a user to download it.

In order to save an octet-stream in Node(CLI) you can use `fs` module:

```js
const data = await fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }).then(res => res.buffer());

fs.writeFile('filename.dat', data, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion.  The file got created,the only content is stores is "[object Blob]".  According to the Postman tool it return good amount of data.  Header indicates Content-Length:1837318.

Comment: I tried to change res.blob() to res.buffer().  It saved whole bunch of data.  I am verifying it now.  I think it did really save it from the quick look.

Comment: @Kay you're right, `res.buffer()` helps. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!!.BTW, when should I consider using downloadjs or  download.js?

Comment: These are front end libraries that trigger the download process in a browser. For instance, when you generate an image on the client (in browser) and want a user to download it.

Comment: Updated the response.